# Antd range slider not updating thumb based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I have created two range sliders. I have used useState to set initial values as shown in the code.
Then I used useEffect to get data from chrome.storage to set the min and max values of the ranges.
But the thumb in the antd sliders are not updating based on the value stored in chrome storage. I am getting the values updated in the state after re-render, but the slider is stuck with the initial value of range [0,1000] and [0,10000]

Here is the code for Slider component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/rangeSlider.module.css";
import { ConfigProvider, Slider } from "antd";

function RangeSlider(props) {
  const [hourly, setHourly] = useState(true);
  const [fixed, setFixed] = useState(true);
  const [hourlyRange, setHourlyRange] = useState([0, 1000]);
  const [fixedRange, setFixedRange] = useState([0, 10000]);

  console.error = (message) => {
    if (
      message.startsWith(
        "[antd: Tooltip] `forcePopupAlign` is align to `forceAlign` instead."
      )
    ) {
      pass;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    chrome.storage.local.get(
      ["job_types", "hourly_min", "hourly_max", "fixed_min", "fixed_max"],
      function (result) {
        let job_types = result.job_types;
        let hourly_min = result.hourly_min;
        let hourly_max = result.hourly_max;
        let fixed_min = result.fixed_min;
        let fixed_max = result.fixed_max;

        try {
          job_types = job_types.split(",");
          job_types.includes("1") ? setHourly(true) : setHourly(false);
          job_types.includes("2") ? setFixed(true) : setFixed(false);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("No job_types in storage");
        }

        try {
          if (hourly_min && hourly_max) {
            console.log("Min and max here: ", hourly_min, hourly_max);
            setHourlyRange([hourly_min, hourly_max]);
            console.log("Updated hourlyRange: ", hourlyRange);
          }
          if (fixed_min && fixed_max) {
            setFixedRange([fixed_min, fixed_max]);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("No Tags in Storage");
        }
      }
    );
  }, []);

  console.log("outside useeffect: ", hourlyRange);

  const handleHourlyChange = (event) => {
    setHourly(event.target.checked);
    const hourly = event.target.checked;
    props.onData(hourly, fixed, hourlyRange, fixedRange);
  };

  const handleFixedChange = (event) => {
    setFixed(event.target.checked);
    const fixed = event.target.checked;
    props.onData(hourly, fixed, hourlyRange, fixedRange);
  };

  const hourlyRangeChange = (value) => {
    // setHourlyRange(value)
    const hourlyRange = value;
    props.onData(hourly, fixed, hourlyRange, fixedRange);
  };

  const fixedRangeChange = (value) => {
    // setFixedRange(value)
    const fixedRange = value;
    props.onData(hourly, fixed, hourlyRange, fixedRange);
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.checkBoxesContainer}>
      <ConfigProvider
        theme={{
          token: {
            colorPrimary: "#b10201",
          },
        }}
      >
        <div className={styles.checkBoxContainer}>
          <label htmlFor="hourly" className={styles.label}>
            Hourly
          </label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="hourly"
            name="job-type"
            value="1"
            checked={hourly}
            onChange={handleHourlyChange}
          />
        </div>
        <Slider
          range
          onAfterChange={hourlyRangeChange}
          min={0}
          max={1000}
          step={5}
          defaultValue={hourlyRange}
          disabled={!hourly}
        />
        <div className={styles.checkBoxContainer}>
          <label htmlFor="fixed_price" className={styles.label}>
            Fixed Price
          </label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="fixed_price"
            name="job-type"
            value="2"
            checked={fixed}
            onChange={handleFixedChange}
          />
        </div>
        <Slider
          range
          onAfterChange={fixedRangeChange}
          min={0}
          max={10000}
          step={50}
          defaultValue={fixedRange}
          disabled={!fixed}
        />
      </ConfigProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RangeSlider;
```

I tried logging the state outside useEffect and it seems to get updated after re-render. But the slider thumbs are always at the 0,1000 and 0,10000 mark

Comment: Use `value` instead of `defaultValue`. Your slider component is controlled by state so slider will use defaultValue once but using `value` prop, it'll always get the latest value